# Spring Boot with JSF2.2 : Error getting customize embedded tomcat

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, jsf-2.2

My Spring boot configuration for jsf is:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet;
import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.MimeMappings;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ServletContextAware, EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean facesServletRegistraiton() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new FacesServlet(), new String[] {"*.jsf", "*.xhtml"});
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return registration;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
        mappings.add("xsd", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        mappings.add("eof", "fa/fontawesome-webfont.eot");
        mappings.add("woff", "fa/fontawesome-webfont.woff");
        mappings.add("ttf", "fa/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
        container.setMimeMappings(mappings);
    }  
}
```

And my pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sjf</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringJSF</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>        
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- SPRING BOOT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>               
        <!-- TOMCAT EMBEDDED -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
          <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
          <version>4.4</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>       
        <!-- JSF -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When we use EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer interface to set mime mapping we got the error:

```
2015-07-17 02:38:25.091 ERROR 8984 --- [           main] javax.faces                              : Unable to obtain InjectionProvider from init time FacesContext. Does this container implement the Mojarra Injection SPI?
2015-07-17 02:38:25.106 ERROR 8984 --- [           main] javax.faces                              : Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. Attempting to find backup.
2015-07-17 02:38:25.106 ERROR 8984 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/app]    : StandardWrapper.Throwable

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:541)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:275)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init(FacesServlet.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1034)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.startConnector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:209)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:667)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:273)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:971)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:960)
    at com.genu.SpringSecuredJSF.Application.main(Application.java:29)
```

Is it anything missing on Facescontext setting? please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra class:

```
@Configuration
public class ContainerCustomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer, Ordered {
    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        ...
    }
}
```